# How to add variable to url. iOS

Tags: json, swift, weather-api

I have a problem with adding my variable to url. 
In code I have this:

```
self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(self.dodatek).png"
```

and this doesn't work. In debugger it shows me this:

```
url String  "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/Optional(\50n\).png"
```

but it should be like this:

```
https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50n.png
```

When I change my code to this:

```
self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/50n.png"
```

it works, and shows me weather icon,but I want to put there my variable that takes icon name from json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like self.dodatek is an `Opional`. You need to unwrap it. I suggest using either `if let` optional binding, or a guard statement:

```
if let filename = self.dodatek {
  self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(filename).png"
}
else {
  print("Error. filename in self.dodatek is nil!")
  return
}
```

Answer (score -3):

It seems like your `self.dodatek` is an optional value. You need to unwrap it by writing `self.dodatek!`, so your string would be:

```
self.imgURL = "https://openweathermap.org/img/w/\(self.dodatek!).png"
```

Comment: Blindly force-unwrapping is a very bad idea. This is very bad advice, especially for a beginner.